# Delaying text printing using the Time module with VSC results in the full text being printed after a while rather than each character one by one?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am facing an odd bug in VSC on Windows 10. I made a simple Python program that print each character of some sample text one by one over time with a constant delay in the printing of each character.

In an IDE like Thonny, this works as expected. Each character is printed after the other slowly. However in VSC, on the latest version, rather than printing each character one by one slowly, absolutely nothing happens for a period of time, and suddenly the entire text is printed all at once

```
import time
def slowText(quote, endChar = '\n'):
    for i in quote:
        print(i, end = endChar)
        time.sleep(0.12)

def intro():
    slowText('Name please?: ', endChar = '')
    name = input()
    slowText(f"You've come to the right place...{name}",endChar = '')

intro()
```

So for instance, here, rather printing each character of 'Name Please?: ' at once, it pauses for a duration of time roughly equal to the total time it would have spent, if it printed each character one by one normally, and suddenly dumps the text 'Name Please?: ' on screen at once

Thonny on the other hand, prints each letter one by one, separated by a 0.12 second gap. Is there a specific reason this issue happens with VSC and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: you are probably having your print output buffered. try adding the flag `flush = True` to your print statement so its not being buffered and is flushed immediatly

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Thank you! That seems to have fixed it! Is there any specific reason flushing the buffer is only required in VSC and not in Thonny?

Comment: it will likley be down to your IDE and its environment. If you set the value of PYTHONUNBUFFERED in the env to true then automatically it will be flushed and not buffered. In pycharm it does this automatically for me and i can verify this with `os.environ['PYTHONUNBUFFERED']` I guess vs code doesnt